# How to monitor region for geofencing using UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey when app is Suspended

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am creating a static library in which I need to implement Geofencing. I have successfully implemented this but the problem is that I want to make region monitoring when the app is suspended/ terminated. 
[My Source Code can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053685/geofencing-in-ios-when-app-is-closed-killed). someone suggest me to achieve this goal using  significant-change location service and `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` but I am unable to do it. Can anybody help me to do it please suggest me any sample code to do it.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW61) that states,

> The region monitoring service delivers events normally while an app is running in the foreground or background. (You can use this service for both geographic and beacon regions.) For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the user.

You can refer [Raywenderlich's great tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift) to know that how to implement it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below link for geofencing:-
https://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift